# Linux initramfs switch_root unable to find console which kernel uses

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, init, yocto, busybox

My system (ARM32) is booting Linux via U-Boot.
The kernel gets `console=ttymxc1,115200` as an argument from u-boot.
Then it uses a shell script with `switch_root` (interpreted by `busybox`) inside a initramfs for initializing the root filesystem.
Furthermore this initramfs script parses the kernel commandline to get the correct `console`.

The problem is that `switch_root` is printing to `tty1`. Nonetheless the kernel uses the correct console, specified in its arguments.
If I pass no `-c` argument to `switch_root` it also uses `/dev/tty1`, which is the display in my case.

Does anybody of you have an idea how I could get `init` (sysvinit) to use the console specified in the kernel arguments?

Here's the initramfs script source:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "init: rootfs setup"

# mount temporary filesystems
mount -n -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
mount -n -t proc     proc     /proc
mount -n -t sysfs    sysfs    /sys
mount -n -t tmpfs    tmpfs    /run

read -r cmdline < /proc/cmdline

# define filesystems
ROOT_DEV="/dev/mydev"
ROOT="/newroot"

# mount rootfs
mkdir -p ${ROOT}
mount ${ROOT_DEV} ${ROOT}

# get & create console
CONSOLE=$(echo $cmdline) | sed 's/.*console=\(.*\),.*/\1/'
mknod -m 644 ${ROOT}/dev/${CONSOLE} c 5 1

# switch to new rootfs and exec init
echo "init: rootfs successful mounted (${ROOT})"
cd ${ROOT}
exec switch_root -c /dev/${CONSOLE} . "/sbin/init" "$@"
```

And here's the initramfs `config.cfg`

```
dir /bin 755 1000 1000
dir /dev 755 0 0
dir /mnt 755 0 0
dir /proc 755 0 0
dir /run 755 0 0
dir /sys 755 0 0
file /bin/busybox initramfs/busybox 755 0 0
file /init initramfs/init 755 0 0
nod /dev/console 644 0 0 c 5 1
nod /dev/ttymxc1 644 0 0 c 5 1
slink /bin/chroot busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/find busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/grep busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/mkdir busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/mknod busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/mount busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/sed busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/sh busybox 777 0 0
```

Comment: which init do you use ? systemd or sysv-init ? switch_root doesn't change tty when no `-c` speficied, I think it is `init` who changes the tty.

Comment: I use sysvinit. Yeah, I know, therefore I've added the `-c /dev/${CONSOLE}` argument ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution (and the mistake I made)!

The console device was created with the wrong major/minor numbers.
Creating it with the same as the kernel assigns to ttymxc* it works:

```
mknod -m 644 ${ROOT}/dev/${CONSOLE} c 207 17
```